# Excel goal seek code

Tags: vba

I tried to use looping with the goal seek in excel but cannot work, would you please correct the code below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   On Error Resume Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Dim i As Integer
   i = 5
   Do While Cells(i, 9) <> ""
   Cells(i, 7).Value = Range("H5").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("I5").Value,       ChangingCell:=Range("A5")
   i = i + 1
   Loop
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it mean "can't work"? Error message, unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "Cells(i, 7).Value =" from the below line.

Return type of goal seek is Boolean.

value is a variant.

```
Range("H5").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("I5").Value, ChangingCell:=Range("A5")
```

Comment: Please look into the below llink for more details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195749(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get the solution for this issue, just to get the benefit of it all please see below answer.

```
Private Sub GoalSeek()


Dim i As Long
For i = 4 To 6
    Range("H" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=Range("I" & i).Value, ChangingCell:=Range("A" & i)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool. I have also provided solution to your issue before you. But you didn't acknowledge it